# Javascript mouseover mouseout with children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have mouseover / mouseout on parent container listening for children (I dont want to attach listener to each individual child)

I cant use mouseenter, mouseleave because they dont bubble.

I cant touch children, or disable in any way (pointer-events etc...)

I dont want children to trigger mouseout if the actual parent hasnt been mouseout. (so mouseover / mouseout has to only happen once even if I move mouse inside the hotspot)

mouseover seems to work , but I cant get mouseout to work.

```js
var holder = document.querySelector('.holder')

holder.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {

  if (e.target.closest('.hotspot') && !e.target.closest('.hotspot').classList.contains('over-hotspot')) {

    console.log('-------------- over hotspot')

    var hotspot = e.target.closest('.hotspot')

    hotspot.classList.add('over-hotspot')

  }

})

holder.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {

  if (e.target.classList.contains('over-hotspot')) {
 // if (e.target.closest('.over-hotspot')) {

    console.log('-------------- out hotspot')

    var hotspot = e.target.closest('.hotspot')

    hotspot.classList.remove('over-hotspot')

  }

})
```

```css
.hotspot {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.hotspot p {}

.foo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">

  <div class="hotspot">
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="foo"></div>
  </div>






</div>
```

Comment: In this case, you could `capture` events that don't bubble. `.addEventListener( handler, { capture: true })`?

Comment: Sorry, where would I use this code in my example?

Comment: There is no drawback to using multiple event listeners

Comment: Isn't it just `holder.addEventListener('mousemove', ..., { capture: true })`? Then get the target with `const target = event,target.querySelector( '.over-hotspot' ) || event.target.closest( '.over-hotspot' );`?